# How to crop the image from the TextureView

Tags: android, view, android-camera2, textureview, android-crop

I want to crop the finger which is shows in the white region (i.e., a view). placed above the `TextureView` using `framelayout`. I've tried capturing the view and converting into bitmap but i doesn't help. Is there any solution available for this? Thanks in Advance.

[image: before cropping]

[image: after cropping]

Comment: check this link [Android-Image-Cropper](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper) it may help you

Comment: @NileshRathod This won't help me in this case. I need to crop automatically after the picture button click.